# What makes a button switch and keep color on click?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a Button that behaves like a switch.

It should change its color when the user clicks it, and keep the color.

So the button is white at first and when the user clicks it, the color changes to black. When the user clicks it again it switches back to white and so on.

I tried it with a simple if else construct but only managed to get the button to be white at first and when being clicked change to black, but it won´t change back to white when clicked again.

Here´s the code so far. I guess it´s a dumb simply mistake but can´t seem to get through with it. "changecolor" is a variable I declared myself.

```
// Select Button Safe or At-Risk
final Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SafeBT);
button7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on clicks, change color
        if (changecolor == 0) {
            button7.setBackgroundColor(color.black);
            changecolor = 1;          
        } else {
            button7.setBackgroundColor(color.white);
            changecolor = 0; 
        }    
    }

});
```

Tanks for advice and help in advance.

Comment: How did you defined changecolor?

Comment: Just beneath "public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {" I entered "int changecolor;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where you have declared your variable changecolor?? .

Second thingis that you can simply an UI Element which call it : ToggleButton , it is like a Switch Button ON/OFF . is that what you want ? see this link  : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. Seemed as a beginner with android I simply overlooked this alternative. Thanks again ^^